# Android KXmlParser "NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.System.arraycopy([CI[CII)V"

Tags: java, android, spock, robolectric, xmlpullparser

I am using KXmlParser in a Spock specification (no Robolectric) to parse Android strings.xml file. I intermittently get the following trace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.System.arraycopy([CI[CII)V

    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.fillBuffer(KXmlParser.java:1509)
    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.peekType(KXmlParser.java:1001)
    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:448)
    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:313)
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Here are are my ext properties:

```
minSdkVersion = 19
targetSdkVersion = 26
compileSdkVersion = 26
buildToolsVersion = '26.0.2'
```

Here is the code snippet:

```
        try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml")) {
            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();
            parser.setInput(in, null);

            AndroidStringResource resource = null;
            int eventType = parser.getEventType();
            while (eventType != parser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                eventType = parser.next();

                if (eventType == parser.START_TAG) {
                    if (parser.getName().equals("string")) {
                        resource = new AndroidStringResource();
                        resource.name = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
                        resource.context = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "context");

                        String maxLengthStr = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "maxLength");
                        resource.maxLength = (maxLengthStr == null) ? -1 : Integer.parseInt(maxLengthStr);
                    }
                } else if (eventType == parser.TEXT) {
                    if (resource != null) {
                        resource.value = parser.getText();
                    }
                } else if (eventType == parser.END_TAG) {
                    if (parser.getName().equals("string")) {

                        if (!resourceNameToServerKeyMap.containsKey(resource.name)) {
                            androidStringResourceMap.put(resource.name, resource);
                        }
                        resource = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Note that I am adding custom XML attributes to  elements in my strings.xml. Here is an example:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name" maxLength="30">myapp</string>
</resources>
```

An MVCE reproduacble test case is avilable [here](https://gist.github.com/farrukhnajmi/ae07e9b1fe1777733c7c523c6fa2679b).

Comment: Could you please post more code of how are trying to fetch and parse.

Comment: Updated. Thanks @SankarGanesh

Comment: Could you please confirm you are able to set the value for the field name and context of the resource object. In addition to that, please let me know at which line the exception is thrown?

Comment: What about this question deserves the tag _spock_? But anyway, your question deserves an answer, of course. I think you are more likely to get a good one if you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with executable code and complete XML attributes file.

Comment: @SankarGanesh The resource.name is always set. The resource.context is set only if a custom context attribute exists on the <string> element. The line in above code causing the exception is "eventType = parser.next();" first line in loop.

The reason I had included spock is that it could be relevant if it pulled the wrong version of a dependency. I have removed the tag.

Comment: @kriegaex it turns out my problem had everything to do with running it in spock and outside the Android runtime. Please see my answer below. Thanks to you and Sankar for trying to help me.

Comment: No, it had nothing to do with Spock but only with the absence of your Android runtime. The same would have happened with JUnit or any other test framework with a similar setup. But I am happy that you found out and solved your problem, congrats to that. :-)

Comment: Glad to hear that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by my using the Spock framework to run the test in a JVM outside the Android VM. This meant that certain code provided by Android runtime was not available to my test. The solution was to use robolectric so that it could provide shadow implementation of Android runtime and still allow my test to run in a JVM outside an Android VM. Once I changed my spock test to use robolectric all was well.